# DynamicRecord Not in use, blockId[2429288]

Tags: neo4j

I have Neo4j 1.9.2 version. The server crashed unexpectedly so the Neo4j server also crashed. I am since then getting the following error on a particular query. I have a backup and the query works on the back. However, the backup is about a month old (of version 1.9.1) and can't be used. Here are the error details. How do I fix the database?

```
InvalidRecordException

DynamicRecord Not in use, blockId[2429288]

StackTrace:
org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.store.AbstractDynamicStore.getRecord(AbstractDynamicStore.java:338)
org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.store.AbstractDynamicStore.getLightRecords(AbstractDynamicStore.java:283)
org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.store.PropertyStore.getRecord(PropertyStore.java:359)
org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.xa.ReadTransaction.loadPropertyValue(ReadTransaction.java:257)
org.neo4j.kernel.impl.persistence.PersistenceManager.loadPropertyValue(PersistenceManager.java:78)
org.neo4j.kernel.impl.core.NodeManager.loadPropertyValue(NodeManager.java:726)
org.neo4j.kernel.impl.core.Primitive.getPropertyValue(Primitive.java:571)
org.neo4j.kernel.impl.core.Primitive.getProperty(Primitive.java:283)
org.neo4j.kernel.impl.core.NodeImpl.getProperty(NodeImpl.java:53)
org.neo4j.kernel.impl.core.NodeProxy.getProperty(NodeProxy.java:140)
org.neo4j.server.helpers.PropertyTypeDispatcher.dispatchProperty(PropertyTypeDispatcher.java:69)
org.neo4j.server.helpers.PropertyTypeDispatcher.consumeProperties(PropertyTypeDispatcher.java:57)
org.neo4j.server.rest.repr.PropertiesRepresentation.serialize(PropertiesRepresentation.java:50)
org.neo4j.server.rest.repr.NodeRepresentation.extraData(NodeRepresentation.java:135)
org.neo4j.server.rest.repr.ObjectRepresentation.serialize(ObjectRepresentation.java:147)
org.neo4j.server.rest.repr.Serializer.serialize(Serializer.java:40)
org.neo4j.server.rest.repr.ListSerializer.addMapping(ListSerializer.java:51)
org.neo4j.server.rest.repr.MappingRepresentation.addTo(MappingRepresentation.java:51)
org.neo4j.server.rest.repr.ListRepresentation.serialize(ListRepresentation.java:60)
org.neo4j.server.rest.repr.Serializer.serialize(Serializer.java:75)
org.neo4j.server.rest.repr.ListSerializer.addList(ListSerializer.java:56)
org.neo4j.server.rest.repr.ListRepresentation.addTo(ListRepresentation.java:67)
org.neo4j.server.rest.repr.ListRepresentation.serialize(ListRepresentation.java:60)
org.neo4j.server.rest.repr.Serializer.serialize(Serializer.java:75)
org.neo4j.server.rest.repr.MappingSerializer.putList(MappingSerializer.java:61)
org.neo4j.server.rest.repr.CypherResultRepresentation.serialize(CypherResultRepresentation.java:57)
org.neo4j.server.rest.repr.MappingRepresentation.serialize(MappingRepresentation.java:41)
org.neo4j.server.rest.repr.OutputFormat.assemble(OutputFormat.java:180)
org.neo4j.server.rest.repr.OutputFormat.formatRepresentation(OutputFormat.java:132)
org.neo4j.server.rest.repr.OutputFormat.response(OutputFormat.java:119)
org.neo4j.server.rest.repr.OutputFormat.ok(OutputFormat.java:57)
org.neo4j.server.rest.web.CypherService.cypher(CypherService.java:95)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
org.neo4j.server.rest.security.SecurityFilter.doFilter(SecurityFilter.java:112)
org.neo4j.server.guard.GuardingRequestFilter.doFilter(GuardingRequestFilter.java:68)
```

Comment: @Peter Neubauer - Hi Peter, I have seen you responding to previous post and about taking a look at the datastore. I would be happy to share that if you are willing to take a look. Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: Would you be able to share your database with us? At least the `graph.db/messages.log` files and the logical log files. Please contact me at michael at neo4j dot org

Comment: Would be glad to share. I just sent you a note.